# Adding the contents of multiple files in php

Tags: php

I could add an additional hits counter to each tracker but the viewing of the data combined will be done less so there's less server load overall.

I'm pulling data from multiple sources. A number stored in text, I want to also be able to display a total.

I assumed this would work. Say the values were `8`, `14` and `11`. The total should be `43` but this only shows me the `8`. Here's what I'm using;

```
<?php echo file_get_contents
("/count/counter1.txt") + 
("/count/counter2.txt") +  
("/count/counter3.txt") ;
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've used `+1` to add hits but the same logic doesn't add the content of each `txt` document.

`EDIT`
Not sure why this is to considered to have answers already when the question is about addition so not the same.

Comment: No php functions allow you to couple additional arguments using plus and new sets of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents
("/count/counter1.txt") + 
("/count/counter2.txt") +  
("/count/counter3.txt") ;
```

This code will do next:

Get content of file /count/counter1.txt and add to him some *("/count/counter2.txt")* (not content of file!).

*("/count/counter2.txt")* is just a string *"/count/counter2.txt"* that translated to number 0, beause this goes for **+** operator

And you get: ***8 + 0 + 0 = 8***

use file_get_contents function on each file:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("/count/counter1.txt") + 
file_get_contents("/count/counter2.txt") +  
file_get_contents("/count/counter3.txt") ;
```